# How to watch any events occurred in SQL Server and integrate it with Maximo

Tags: integration, tivoli, maximo

I have a request to integrate Maximo with another system which use SQL Server DB, let's call it System 1
System 1, add or update person in database, i want to watch this change and create or update person record in Maximo accordingly,
Any suggestions of how to implement this scenario? 
Also, i have heard about Integration Composer, can it help?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

What version of Maximo are you using? In 7, the Maximo integration framework (mif) allows you to integrate via csv, XML, or interface table. You use the Maximo mbos (Maximo business objects) so validation is performed by the application. Inserting data via database is possible but that can cause issues.

For example, email address and phone is stored in a secondary table (non persistent field). You have to be careful if you are inserting data via the back end. Using mif, you would not have these data integrity concerns.

Comment: Sun W Kim, Thank you for your reply, i'm using Maximo 7.5, I don't want to insert data directly in database, i want to insert it through the application, I have already developed application which watch events occurred in SQL Server then call Maximo Web Service to insert the extracted data, 
However, I can't trust this application, so i'm currently trying to implement it through any IBM tools, it is more reliable and trusted,

Comment: Yes, that's what Maximo Integration Framework (MIF) was designed for. If you want to use XML, here are some more specifics for you: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/a9ba1efe-b731-4317-9724-a181d6155e3a/entry/resting_with_maximo1?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

You can create a CLR (trigger) appication in Visual Studios that listens to SQL Server database insert, update and delete

In VS Click start -> New Project -->Database --> SQL Server  --> Visual c# CLR Database Project.

You can read some online tuturials to get started

link: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/19/sql-server-introduction-to-clr-simple-example-of-clr-stored-procedure/

Comment: demo, thank you for your proposed resolution, i already did that using visual studio, but customer wants it through IBM tools not customized

Comment: You can call a webservice from the CLR trigger application and pass all parameters to your maximo.